# MEAN : Getting 500 Error while trying to register a user in Flapper news example

Tags: mongodb, passport.js, mean-stack, mean

I am tying to learn MEAN Stack and trying to create a app for Flapper news as given in one of the [site](https://thinkster.io/mean-stack-tutorial). I am trying to create a register and login functionality using passport.

But when i am trying to register a user it returns a 500 Internal Server Error. To be exact below error in the console.

**"NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://localhost:3000/register"**

I am naive in these technologies. Any help would be must appriaciated. Thanks in advance.

My code goes like.

**User.js** - User schema

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var crypto = require('crypto');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
username : {type: String, lowercase: true, unique : true},
hash : String,
salt : String
});

mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

UserSchema.methods.setPassword = function(password){
this.salt = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex');
this.hash = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, this.salt, 1000, 64).toString('hex');
};

UserSchema.methods.validPassword = function(password) {
var hash = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, this.salt, 1000, 64).toString('hex');

return this.hash === hash;
};

UserSchema.methods.generateJWT = function() {

// ste expiration to 60 days
var today = new Date();
var exp = new Date(today);
exp.setDate(today.getDate() + 60);

return jwt.sign({
    _id: this._id,
    username : this.username,
    exp : parseInt(exp.getTime() / 1000),
}, 'SECRET');
};
```

**angularAppJS** - Main JS

```
var app = angular.module('flapperNews', ['ui.router'])
.config([
    '$stateProvider', 
    '$urlRouterProvider', 
    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
        $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url : '/home',
            templateUrl: '/home.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl',
            resolve : {
                postPromise : ['posts', function(posts){
                    return posts.getAll();
                }]
            }
        })
        .state('posts', {
            url : '/posts/{id}',
            templateUrl : '/posts.html',
            controller : 'PostsCtrl',
            resolve : {
                post : ['$stateParams', 'posts', function($stateParams, posts){
                    return posts.get($stateParams.id);
                }] 
            }
        })
        .state('login', {
          url: '/login',
          templateUrl: '/login.html',
          controller: 'AuthCtrl',
          onEnter: ['$state', 'auth', function($state, auth){
            if(auth.isLoggedIn()){
              $state.go('home');
            }
          }]
        })
        .state('register', {
          url: '/register',
          templateUrl: '/register.html',
          controller: 'AuthCtrl',
          onEnter: ['$state', 'auth', function($state, auth){

            if(auth.isLoggedIn()){
              $state.go('home');
            }
          }]
        });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
}]) 
.factory('posts', ['$http',  'auth', function($http, auth){
    var o = {
        posts : []
    };
    o.getAll = function(){
        return $http.get('/posts').success(function(data){
            angular.copy(data, o.posts);
        });
    };
    o.create = function(post) {
        return $http.post('/posts', post, {
            headers: {Authorization: 'Bearer '+auth.getToken()}
        }).success(function(data){
            o.posts.push(data);
        });
    };
    o.upvote = function(post) {
        return $http.put('/posts/' + post._id + '/upvote', null,{
            headers: {Authorization: 'Bearer '+auth.getToken()}
        }).success(function(data){
            post.upvotes += 1;
        });
    };
    o.get = function(id){
        return $http.get('/posts/' + id).then(function(res){
            return res.data;
        });
    };
    o.addComment = function(id, comment) {
        return $http.post('/posts/' + id + '/comments', comment, {
            headers: {Authorization: 'Bearer '+auth.getToken()}
        });
    };
    o.upvoteComment = function(post, comment) {
        return $http.put('/posts/' + post._id + '/comments/' + comment._id + '/upvote', null, {
            headers : {Authorization: 'Bearer'+auth.getToken()}
        }).success(function(data){
            comment.upvotes += 1;
        });
    };

    return o;
}])
.factory('auth', ['$http', '$window', function($http, $window){
    var auth = {};

    auth.saveToken = function(token){
        $window.localStorage['flapper-news-token'] = token;
    };

    auth.getToken = function(){
        return $window.localStorage['flapper-news-token'];
    };

    auth.isLoggedIn  = function(){
        var token = auth.getToken();

        if(token){
            var payload = JSON.parse($window.atob(token.split('.')[1]));

            return payload.exp >  Date.now() / 1000;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    };

    auth.currentUser = function() {
        if(auth.isLoggedIn()){
            var token = auth.getToken();
            var payload = JSON.parse($window.atob(token.split('.')[1]));

            return payload.username;
        }
    };

    auth.register = function(user){
        return $http.post('/register', user).success(function(data){
            auth.saveToken(data.token);
        });
    };

    auth.logIn = function(user){
        return $http.post('/login', user).success(function(data){
            auth.saveToken(data.token);
        });
    };

    auth.logOut = function(){
        $window.localStorage.removeItem('flapper-news-token');
    };

    return auth;
}])
.controller('MainCtrl', [
'$scope', 
'posts',
'auth',
function($scope, posts){
    $scope.posts =posts.posts;
    $scope.isLoggedIn = auth.isLoggedIn;

    $scope.addPost = function(){
        if(!$scope.title || $scope.title === '') {return;}
        posts.create({
            title : $scope.title,
            link : $scope.link
        });
        $scope.title = '';
        $scope.link = '';
    };
    $scope.incrementUpvotes = function(post) {
        posts.upvote(post);
    };
}])
.controller('PostsCtrl', [
    '$scope', 
    'posts', 
    'post', 
    'auth',
    function($scope, posts, post){
        $scope.post = post;
        $scope.isLoggedIn = auth.isLoggedIn;

        $scope.addComment = function(){
            if($scope.body === '') {return;}
            posts.addComment(post._id, {
                body : $scope.body,
                author: 'user'
            }).success(function(comment){
                $scope.post.comments.push(comment);
            });
            $scope.body = '';
        };
        $scope.incrementUpvotes = function(comment) {
            posts.upvoteComment(post, comment);
        };
}])
.controller('NavCtrl',[
    '$scope',
    'auth',
    function($scope, auth){
        $scope.isLoggedIn = auth.isLoggedIn;
        $scope.currentUser = auth.currentUser;
        $scope.logOut = auth.logOut;
}])
.controller('AuthCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    '$state',
    'auth',
    function($scope, $state, auth){
        $scope.user = {};

        $scope.register = function(){
            auth.register($scope.user).error(function(error){
                $scope.error = error;
            }).then(function(){
                $state.go('home');
            });
        };

        $scope.logIn = function(){
            auth.logIn($scope.user).error(function(error){
                $scope.error = error;
            }).then(function(){
                $state.go('home');
            });
        };
    }]);
```

Please let me know if any other information is needed.

Comment: And what about error on the server, anything? The error you getting is from browser's console, right?

Comment: @Molda I am not sure about the error on server. Yes this is from browser`s console.

Comment: @PriyankShrivastava Did u resolve this....am getting the same error